# How to pass a value in a .net label through Javascript

Tags: javascript, ado.net

I am coding in c# and javascript and I have some problems with setting a  value  through a javascript `.js` file, in order to use it in the code behind.

This is the `.js` file code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#example1').ratings(10).bind('ratingchanged', function(event, data) {
    $('#examplerating1').text(data.rating);
$('#lblRating').text(data.Rating);

  });
```

And this is the html page code.

```
 Your Rating: <span id="examplerating1">not set</span>
            <asp:Label ID="lblRating" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Now the span value is setted correctly if I not use the `runat="server"`. Now in order to access the value in the code behind i tried to put it in a label. But the value is not setted in the label. How can I use the data.rating value in the code behind passing though the HTML page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net controls ID gets changed based on the NamingContainer.

Change your jQuery to as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example1').ratings(10).bind('ratingchanged', function(event, data) {
    $('#examplerating1').text(data.rating);
    //Notice the change in the selector here.
    $('[id$="_lblRating"').text(data.Rating);

  });
```

Comment: Yes I am using a Master Page, I changed the code `$('[id$="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblRating"').text(data.Rating);` but the problem is not solved... the Label remains empty

Comment: Can you post the HTML generated for the label?

Comment: `<asp:Label ID="lblRating" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>`

Comment: That is aspx. Can you post the html that is sent to browser. Right click on browser and select view source.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rest of your code. If you have the label inside another .NET control, such as a master page, the span ID generated by .NET isn't the same as the ID you assigned in the .aspx file. For example, if it is inside a Content control named ContentPlaceHolder1, the ID will be ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblRating.  As Cybernate says above, the ID that is generated depends on the NamingContainer that the label is part of.

Comment: Yes I am using a Master Page, I changed the code `$('[id$="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblRating"').text(data.Rating);` but the problem is not solved... the Label remains empty

Comment: You have to make sure that it the actual name that ASP.NET is generating. If your Content tag is named differently, or if there are more container controls besides just the master page, the ID will be different. Do a view source on the file, and search for lblRating or whatever your control ID is assigned in the aspx file. If the Javascript is emitted in the aspx file instead of in a separate .js file, you can also use `<%=lblRating.ClientID%>` inside the javascript (I think!). Each control has a .ClientID property that will be the ID that ASP.NET is going to assign it in the HTML.